# Inconsistency between read-key and read-key-sequence-vector w.r.t. conditional application of local-function-key-map translations

Tags: help, documentation, events, read, key-translation-map

While working with `read-key-sequence-vector` and `read-key`, I found that the former applies the `local-function-key-map` translations in a conditional manner but the latter does not. I am using Emacs 28.1 on a macOS system.

The function `read-key-sequence-vector` translates the original key sequence to a key sequence in the `local-function-key-map` only if the original key sequence is unbound. If the original key sequence is bound, then the translations in `local-function-key-map` are not applied.

However, according to my observations, the function `read-key` always seems to apply the `local-function-key-map` translations in an unconditional manner. I would like to understand if this is a bug or expected behavior. The sections below explain the investigation I have done so far.

#### Documentation: read-key-sequence-vector

The documentation for `read-key-sequence-vector` at [§ 22.8.1 Key Sequence Input](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Key-Sequence-Input.html) refers to `read-key-sequence` which says:

> **Function: read-key-sequence *prompt &optional continue-echo dont-downcase-last switch-frame-ok command-loop***
>
> ...
>
> Reading a key sequence includes translating the events in various ways. See [Keymaps for Translating Sequences of Events](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Translation-Keymaps.html).

The documentation for [§ 23.14 Keymaps for Translating Sequences of Events](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Translation-Keymaps.html) says:

> **Variable: local-function-key-map**
>
> This variable holds a keymap similar to `input-decode-map` except that it describes key sequences which should be translated to alternative interpretations that are usually preferred. It applies after `input-decode-map` and before `key-translation-map`.
>
> Entries in `local-function-key-map` are ignored if they conflict with bindings made in the minor mode, local, or global keymaps. I.e., the remapping only applies if the original key sequence would otherwise not have any binding.

Now open a fresh new Emacs:

```
emacs -q
```

Then type:

```
C-h v local-function-key-map RET
```

The output contains this entry:

```
 (tab .
      [9])
```

Confirm the above observation by entering the following:

```
M-: (lookup-key local-function-key-map [tab]) RET
```

It should display the following output:

```
[9]
```

We have seen so far that if the `<tab>` key is unbound, then a key sequence `[tab]` should get translated to `[9]`. We'll see an example of this in an experiment presented later.

#### Documentation: read-key

The documentation for `read-key` at [§ 22.8.2 Reading One Event](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Reading-One-Event.html) says:

> **Function: read-key *&optional prompt disable-fallbacks***
>
> This function reads a single key. It is intermediate between `read-key-sequence` and `read-event`. Unlike the former, it reads a single key, not a key sequence. Unlike the latter, it does not return a raw event, but decodes and translates the user input according to `input-decode-map`, `local-function-key-map`, and `key-translation-map` (see [Keymaps for Translating Sequences of Events](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Translation-Keymaps.html)).

It seems that the translation rules that apply for `read-key` are no different from that of `read-key-sequence-vector`. The same documentation further says:

> If argument *disable-fallbacks* is non-`nil` then the usual fallback logic for unbound keys in `read-key-sequence` is not applied. This means that mouse button-down and multi-click events will not be discarded and `local-function-key-map` and `key-translation-map` will not get applied. If `nil` or unspecified, the only fallback disabled is downcasing of the last event.

The `disable-fallbacks` argument if set to `t` unconditionally *skips* translations, so this argument does not seem relevant to my question here. My question here is about `read-key` unconditionally *applying* translations, not about unconditionally *skipping* translations.

#### Experiment 1: Default Behaviour

Switch to a fundamental mode buffer:

```
C-x b foo RET
```

Now type the following:

```
C-h k <tab>
```

The following output should appear:

```
TAB (translated from <tab>) runs the command indent-for-tab-command
(found in global-map), which is an interactive compiled Lisp function
in ‘indent.el’.
```

It shows that `<tab>` (represented as the symbol `tab` in the key sequence vector as we'll see later) is unbound and it is being translated to `TAB` (also something we'll see soon).

Copy this Elisp code into the buffer:

```
(defun check-keys ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((event (read-event "Event: "))
    (key (read-key "Key: "))
    (key-sequence-vector (read-key-sequence-vector "Key Sequence: ")))
    (message "event: %S (%S); key: %S (%S); key-sequence-vector: %S (%S)"
         event (type-of event)
         key (type-of key)
         key-sequence-vector (type-of key-sequence-vector))))
```

Now define this command by placing the cursor after the last parentheses and typing the following:

```
C-x C-e
```

Now execute the above command by typing:

```
M-x check-keys RET
```

This command prompts three times. Type <kbd>tab</kbd> all three times. The following output appears:

```
event: tab (symbol); key: 9 (integer); key-sequence-vector: [9] (vector)
```

This is expected behaviour. The function `read-event` reads the next event (a <kbd>tab</kbd> key) as the symbol `tab`. Since there is nothing bound to the key sequence `[tab]` (a vector containing the symbol `tab`), both `read-key` and `read-key-sequence-vector` translate it according to `local-function-key-map` thereby obtaining `9`.

#### Experiment 2: Key Sequence [tab] Bound

Now define a key-binding for a key sequence containing the symbol `tab` as follows:

```
M-: (global-set-key [tab] 'whitespace-mode) RET
```

Now verify the key binding with the following key sequence:

```
C-h k <tab>
```

The following output appears confirming that the `<tab>` key itself is bound to the `whitespace-command` command:

```
<tab> runs the command whitespace-mode (found in global-map), which is
an autoloaded interactive Lisp function in ‘whitespace.el’.
```

Now run `check-keys` again:

```
M-x check-keys RET
```

Once again, type <kbd>tab</kbd> at all three prompts. The following output appears:

```
event: tab (symbol); key: 9 (integer); key-sequence-vector: [tab] (vector)
```

Now the key sequence made of the symbol `tab` *is* bound to the `whitespace-mode` command. Therefore according to [§ 23.14 Keymaps for Translating Sequences of Events](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Translation-Keymaps.html), the symbol `tab` should not be translated to the integer `9` anymore. In fact, the above output shows that `read-key-sequence-vector` indeed does not translate the symbol `tab` to the integer `9` anymore. This shows that the conditional translation is working as documented in `read-key-sequence-vector`.

However, the above output also shows that `read-key` still translates the symbol `tab` to the integer `9`. The behaviour of `read-key` here seems to contradict [§ 22.8.2 Reading One Event](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Reading-One-Event.html) which seems to imply that the conditional translation rules for `local-function-key-map` should apply here too, i.e., no translation for `tab` should occur when it is already bound to some command.

Does the behaviour of `read-key` indeed contradict the documentation? Or is this expected behaviour? If this is expected behaviour, where in the documentation can we find why this is expected behaviour?